# Attribute Value Saperator

Tags: html, attributes, meta

What's the right way?

1. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`
2. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />`

   ---

what **separator** must we use?

1. comma: `,`
2. semicolon: `;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp